# entitlements files in Java app to publish in App Store

Tags: macos, app-store, entitlements

I have a Java app, converted in a bundle .app, and then in a pkg to be able to publish in App Store.

They told me this:

```
App sandbox not enabled - The following executables must include the "com.apple.security.app-sandbox" entitlement with a Boolean value of true in the entitlements property list. Refer to the App Sandbox page for more information on sandboxing your app.

MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaAppLauncher
MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jspawnhelper
```

Obviously, I'm not using XCode, since it's a Java app.

How can I create the entitlements.plist for those two files ?

AFAIK entitlements.plist needs this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

But I don't know where to place it ... in root folder? Then why have they asked me entitlements for those 2 specific files ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating this file in the ROOT FOLDER of your proyect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: AppLoader is still complaining: ERROR ITMS-9000: "App sandbox not enabled. The following executables must include the "com.apple.security.app-sandbox" entitlement with a Boolean value of true in the entitlements property list: [( "com.myapp.pkg/Payload/MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jspawnhelper" )]